# Clear eval in Leksah

Tags: haskell, leksah

I am not sure this is the right place to ask this question. If it isn't - my apologies.

In Leksah I can right click and choose `eval`, which then prints evaluated messages to the log.

I can then select a different function to `eval`, but I cannot clear it all together so that nothing is `eval`ed.